# How old does English ivy (Hedera helix var.) have to be in order to flower?

Tags: flowering, english-ivy

I like the look of flowering ivy, but mine has never shown a sign of a flower. Is it one of those plants that takes a long time or am I not caring for it properly? Mine is five years old and climbed 25' up the wall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's like a lot of vines - it has to get woody, with dark leaves.  This takes several years.  If you prune it hard each year, it will stay juvenile and never flower.